# AudioInputStream is throwing NullPointerException

Tags: url, audio, nullpointerexception, clip, audioinputstream

I have been looking for a way to export a JAR file from my project that manages to always play the sound files no matter where it is located. For this I wrote the following code that returns an exact path to the file.

```
public MouseHandler() {
    playSound("rsc/click.wav");
}
public void playSound(final String fileName) {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try {
        URL fileUrl = file.toURI().toURL();
        String urls = fileUrl.toString();
        urls = urls.replaceFirst("file:/", "file:///");
        System.out.println(urls);
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem
                .getAudioInputStream(MouseHandler.class.getResourceAsStream(urls));
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I have the AudioInputStream open the file as a stream, it throws a NullPointerException even though the URL has a value before.

```
file:///X:/workspace/eclipse/Minesweeper/rsc/click.wav
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:222)
at java.desktop/javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1006)
at configs.MouseHandler.playSound(MouseHandler.java:62)
[AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem
                .getAudioInputStream(MouseHandler.class.getResourceAsStream(urls));]
at configs.MouseHandler.<init>(MouseHandler.java:45)
[playSound("rsc/click.wav");]
at configs.Button.<init>(Button.java:57)
at gui.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:81)
at start.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

I know this doesn't happen if I give the AudioInputStream `"rsc/click.wav"`, but then the file is not found when I export the project. If there is another way to export a project that can still play the audio files, I would like to use that if it works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info This link has two examples for loading content: via a remote URL, or from a file that is included as part of the jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution with stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info worked for me, thank you very much!

```
public void playSound(final URL fileName) throws Exception {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fileName);
                AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 2, 4, 44100, false);
                Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
                SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
                int bytesRead = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                sourceDataLine.start();
                while ((bytesRead = audioInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    sourceDataLine.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                sourceDataLine.drain();
                sourceDataLine.stop();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```